# How can I enable CloudWatchLogs in an ElasticBeanstalk environment running Windows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a webservice that spools out data to a flat file. In non-EC2, raw Windows instances we use the  EC2Config service to pump our log files and some performance counters to CloudWatch (See here: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx1KG4IKXZ94QFK/Using-CloudWatch-Logs-with-Amazon-EC2-Running-Microsoft-Windows-Server ).

How can I configure my application and ElasticBeanstalk to enable CloudWatch Logging in my Windows Instance?

Comment: Does this help? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html

Comment: The AWS documentation in general (and specifically that linked page) is Linux-specific

Comment: By default IIS-Logs,EBHooks and EBDeploy log files are sent to cloudwatch logs during the stack creation. But any custom Application, Windows Event logs are not supported out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I use an .ebextensions file for this purpose. The following cloudwatch.config file is in the .ebextensions directory of my application root. It installs the agent, sets it up as a service, and updates the configuration. The metrics are chosen from the list available from perfmon.

```
packages:
  msi:
    cloudwatch: https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/windows/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.msi
services:
  windows:
    AmazonCloudWatchAgent:
      enabled: 'true'
      ensureRunning: 'true'
      files:
        - "C:/ProgramData/Amazon/AmazonCloudWatchAgent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json"
files:
  "C:/ProgramData/Amazon/AmazonCloudWatchAgent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json":
    content: |
      {
        "metrics": {
          "namespace": "suprep",
          "append_dimensions": {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
            "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}",
            "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
            "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
          },
          "metrics_collected": {
            "LogicalDisk": {
              "measurement": [
                "% Free Space",
                "Avg. Disk Bytes/Transfer"
              ],
              "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
              "resources": [
                "C:"
              ]
            },
            "Memory": {
              "measurement": [
                "Available MBytes",
                "Page Faults/sec",
                "% Committed Bytes In Use"
              ],
              "metrics_collection_interval": 60
            },
            "Network Interface": {
              "measurement": [
                "Bytes Total/sec"
              ],
              "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
              "resources": [
                "_Total"
              ]
            },
            "Paging File": {
              "measurement": [
                "% Usage"
              ],
              "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
              "resources": [
                "_Total"
              ]
            },
            "Process": {
              "measurement": [
                "% Processor Time",
                "Private Bytes"
              ],
              "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
              "resources": [
                "dotnet"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "aggregation_dimensions" : [["AutoScalingGroupName"], ["InstanceId"],[]],
        "logs": {
          "logs_collected": {
            "files": {
              "collect_list": [
                {
                  "file_path": "c:\\Windows\\Temp\\log*.txt",
                  "log_group_name": "MyLogGroup",
                  "timezone": "UTC"
                }
              ]
            },
            "windows_events": {
              "collect_list": [
                {
                  "event_name": "System",
                  "event_levels": [
                    "WARNING",
                    "ERROR"
                  ],
                  "log_group_name": "MyLogGroup",
                  "log_stream_name": "System",
                  "event_format": "xml"
                },
                {
                  "event_name": "Application",
                  "event_levels": [
                    "WARNING",
                    "ERROR"
                  ],
                  "log_group_name": "MyLogGroup",
                  "log_stream_name": "Application",
                  "event_format": "xml"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "log_stream_name": "MyLogStream"
        }
      }
commands:
  01_stop_service:
    command: powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "C:\\'Program Files'\\Amazon\\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\\amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl.ps1 -a stop"
  02_start_service:
    command: powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "C:\\'Program Files'\\Amazon\\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\\amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl.ps1 -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:C:\\ProgramData\\Amazon\\AmazonCloudWatchAgent\\amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json -s"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just append logs to the original ones set up by Elastic Beanstalk, use the answer from @mike-mckechnie, but don't include the `stop` command at the bottom. You'll also need to replace `fetch-config` with `append-config`